# Existing Windows Service omits "new System.ComponentModel.Container()", but still works. What does this do?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm diagnosing why a particular service omits a call to `System.ComponentModel.Container()`, and I would like to understand the purpose of this object, and what it is used for.

Ideally, I'd also like to understand what is expected to happen if the class level variable is set to null.

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.ServiceName = "Service1";
    }
```

One theoretical explanation is to hide the service from `net service` and the services.mmc.  There are likely better approaches to accomplish this, without risking runtime operation of the service.

Comment: The container is for putting special objects there. Don't assign it if you don't need it